# selectOneMenu default value does not work in table row editor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a p:selectOneMenu tag in a p:cellEditor tag of a table with roweditor.
here is it's code:

```
 <p:column headerText="Update Interval">
           <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{news.intervalLabel}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{newsManagementBean.intervals}" valueChangeListener="#{newsManagementBean.changedIntervals}" style="width: 200px;">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{newsManagementBean.updateIntervals}" var="interval" itemLabel="#{interval.value}"
                                                   itemValue="#{interval.key}"/>
                     </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
          </p:cellEditor>
 </p:column>
```

variable interval is an enum for menu items, and news is variable defined in table. I want when I click edit button for editing row, default value of selectOneMenu be actual value of news's interval, but when I click edit it does not show default value that I set for it and show enum values only.

The first value of enum is 5 and it shows 5 for every row as default value of selectOneMenu.

Comment: item label is not my problem! read question again.

Comment: Please show an mcve (see [ask] and the jsf info page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have a table it means you have different objects each has their own `intervals` so It's better not to use a single value `#{newsManagementBean.intervals}` for all of them. try defining `intervals` as your object's property and use it in that way. I mean `news.intervals`

Comment: How do you know it is a single value used for all? The code is to limited to know. Better ask for clarification/improvement of the code first